# My program is trying to figure out ranges, averages, and highscores of a students test scores

Tags: java

The getRange() works, and the getAverage() works, but the getHighScore() doesn't seem to work. It always comes out with the answer 0. I'm using a 4 point system in my code for highscore, so if a person get an average of 95 and a range of 5, they would get a highscore of 5. Which is then divided by 5 and multiplied by 4 to keep the answer out of 4.

```
public int getAverage() //Gets average of test scores
{
    //Compute and return the average
    int average;
    average = (int) Math.round((test1 + test2 + test3) / 3.0); //Rounds the average number
    return average;
}

public int getRange() //Gets range of test scores
    {
        int range;
        range = 0;
        if (test1 >= test2 && test1 >= test3)
            if (test2 >= test3)
                range = test1-test3;
            else if (test3 >= test2)
                range = test1-test2;
        if (test2 >= test1 && test2 >= test3)
            if (test1 >= test3)
                range = test2-test3;
            else if (test3 >= test1)
                range = test2-test1;
        if (test3 >= test1 && test3 >= test2)
            if (test1 >= test2)
                range = test3-test2;
            else if (test2 >= test1)
                range = test3-test1;
        return range;
    }

public double getHighScore() //Formula for finding highscore with the use of getAverage() and getRange()

{
        double highscore;
        highscore = 0;
        if (getAverage() >= 90)
            highscore = highscore + 4;
        else if (getAverage() >= 80 && getAverage() < 90)
            highscore = highscore + 3;
        else if (getAverage() >= 70 && getAverage() < 80)
            highscore = highscore + 2;
        else if (getAverage() >= 60 && getAverage() < 70)
            highscore = highscore + 1;
        else
            highscore = highscore + 0;
        if (getRange() <= 10)
            highscore = highscore + 1;
        else if (getRange() <=20 && getRange() > 10)
            highscore = highscore + (3/4);
        else if (getRange() <=30 && getRange() > 20)
            highscore = highscore + (2/4);
        else if (getRange() <=40 && getRange() > 30)
            highscore = highscore + (1/4);
        else
            highscore = highscore+0;
        highscore = highscore*(4/5);
        return highscore;
    }
```

Comment: On a side note, I would recommend always using `{}` in your if statements, regardless if it is a one line statement. Saves you a lot of time when you (or someone else) adds more code to your if statements and your program suddenly breaks and you can't figure out why.

Comment: since there is already an answer just a small hint: you use `getAverage()` and `getRange()` over and over again, this means you compute this values in worst case about 15 times. You should compute this values 1 time, save it in a variable and process your if-else with this variables.

Comment: You could use more math knowledge to shorten your function. E.g. you could simple write `getRange()` as `return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(test1, test2, test3)) - Collections.min(Arrays.asList(test1, test2, test3));`

Comment: another hint: `else if (getAverage() >= 80 && getAverage() < 90)` in all of your else-if-statements you don't need the second statement, since if you are in this `else` the value is already < 90

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably with this line:

```
highscore = highscore*(4/5);
```

The reason is, integer division (4/5) is returning 0, you can try with:

```
highscore = highscore*(4.0/5.0);
```

Change your all integer division to decimal division.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been bugging me for a while. Who knew it could be such a simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in the line prior to returning `highscore`

```
highscore = highscore * (4 / 5);
```

Specifically `(4/5)` will always yield 0 as it is Integer Division.

In fact you have them in multiple places like:

```
highscore = highscore + (3/4);
highscore = highscore + (2/4);
highscore = highscore + (1/4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're just a student at the beginning of learning, but this code can't scale.

Think about decomposing things into smaller methods that you can test individually.

```
public class Stats {

    public static double sum(double [] values) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        if (values != null) {
            for (double value : values) {
                sum += value;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static double min(double [] values) {
        double minValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        if (values != null) {
            for (double value : values) {
                if (value < minValue) {
                    minValue = value;
                }
            }
        }
        return minValue;
    }


    public static double max(double [] values) {
        double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        if (values != null) {
            for (double value : values) {
                if (value > mAXValue) {
                    maxValue = value;
                }
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    public static double ave(double [] values) {
        double ave = 0.0;
        if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
            ave = sum(values)/values.length;
        }
        return ave;
    }
}
```